# in R count number of people who answered for 3 and do not include answers as -3 or 13

Tags: r

I'm working on questionnaire data and I have a multiple choice question and I want to count how many people answered each of the options.

For example, in the table below, I want to count the following:

answer is 3 should have count 3
answer is 13 should have count 1
answer is -3 should have count 1

(answer column is a list variable)

[image]

I'm using the str_detect function:

```
sum(str_detect(data$answers,"3"))
```

but than -3 and 13 are also counted

I saw that you can add \b (boundaries)

```
sum(str_detect(data$answers,"\\b3"))
```

but it doesn't seem to work, anyone any ideas?

Comment: You can apply str_split first to separate all the options you've in answer column and  use str_count instread of str_detect like this : sapply(str_split(data$answers, ","), function(x) sum(str_count(x, "3")))

Comment: Please include a sample of your dataset to your question in a reproducible form, i.e. output from `dput(head(data))`.  A screenshot might seem convenient, but it hides your actual data  types and forces others to  come up with their own interpretations. It's super-easy to get it wrong when something seems to be a string but is described as something else ("a list variable").

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
> strsplit(df$answer, ',') |> sapply(\(x) all(x != -3 & x != 13) & any(x == 3))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, answer = c("1,2,3,4", "3,6,9", "2,3,13", 
"-3", "1,6,9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have each number only once per ID and you are just interested in counts of each answer you can just use table on all values in answer. Also I assume your data is indeed such that answer is a list and not a string with comma seperated values.

```
table(unlist(df$answer))

-3  1  2  3  4  6  9 13 
 1  2  2  3  1  2  2  1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, answer = list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(3, 6, 9), c(2, 3, 13), -3, c(1, 6, 9))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

**EDIT**

If you have strings, you can do

```
table(unlist(strsplit(df$answer, ",")))
```

and if you only want to have the results of 3, 13 and -3 you can subset like this

```
table(unlist(strsplit(df$answer, ",")))[c("3", "13", "-3")]

 3 13 -3 
 3  1  1
```